# Looking for the best way to populate objects with JSON.net using references

Tags: c#, json, unity-game-engine

I am using JSON.net in Unity to save my game data. I created a Savegame-class that contains all the data I want to save. Let's say I got a List of Characters and a Player object, that contains a reference to one of those characters. Using the PreserveReferencesHandling, the resulting JSON is looking like expected:

```
{
  "characters":[
    {
      "$id": "1",
      "name": "char1",
      "reputation": 100
    },
...
  "player": {
    "location": "town1",
      "character": {
        "$ref": "1"
      }
  }
}
```

When I deserialize the Savegame, the Character-List and Player are restored and the reference to the Character is set.
I COULD now assign the Player object from the Savegame back to the Player object in my GameManager, where the Player is used throughout the game.

So in short: GameManager.Player gets referenced by Savegame which is then serialized. Upon loading a new Player with the saved data is created in Savegame and Savegame.Player gets assigned to GameManager.Player.

The problem is, that every part of the game that had a reference to the GameManager.Player now are still referencing the old Player-object while the GameManager.Player now holds a new reference to the newly created Player (I hope I am making sense).

So I could make sure no Player references are being cached or what I am trying to do, I could populate the existing Player with the data from the Savegame. JSON.net provides a method for that named `JsonConvert.PopulateObject(string value, object target)`. So I parsed the JSON and grabbed the Player out of it but populating the Character inside the Player was not very successful because that part of the JSON only had the reference without data in it.

So my question is: how do I populate objects with those references when grabbing them out of the whole context?

Simplified snippets of code below.

```
public class GameManager{
  public static GameManager instance; //singleton

  public List<Character> characters;
  public Player player; //<-- other classes may have a ref to this

  //...
}

public class Character{
  public string name;
  public int reputation;
  //...
}

public class Player{
  public string location;
  public Character character;
  //...
}

public class Savegame{
  public List<Character> characters;
  public Player player;

  public Savegame(){
    characters=GameManager.instance.characters;
    player=GameManager.instance.player;
  }

  public static void Save(){
    string saveJson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new Savegame(), Formatting.Indented,
        new JsonSerializerSettings { PreserveReferencesHandling = PreserveReferencesHandling.Objects });
        string dest = Path.Combine(Application.persistentDataPath, "gmSave.json");
        File.WriteAllText(dest, saveJson);
  }

  public static void Load(){
    string dest = Path.Combine(Application.persistentDataPath, "gmSave.json");
    string saveJson = File.ReadAllText(dest);
    Savegame savegame = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Savegame>(saveJson);
    JObject jo = JObject.Parse(saveJson);    
    JsonConvert.PopulateObject(jo["player"].ToString(), GameManager.instance.player);
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you post the actual code, it will be easier to reason and help you. I don't follow how the referencing is done.

Comment: Thanks ipinak, I added the essential pieces above.

Answer (score 0):

Use `JSONUtility` instead for classes this simple.

You should not be populating objects.

Comment: If I am not populating the objects but instead creating new ones, all references to the old one will now point to an object that is "old", meaning all changes to the new object will not be seen by any object that had a reference to the old object.

To clarify: if you have a contract to use a car that is in garage A and that car gets repaired from time to time you always have a working car. But if after the repair a copy is made and put in garage B and then only car B gets repaired then your car someday will not work anymore ;)